# How to check selected date is this month or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to validate if the date selected in the datepicker is the same month as the current month or not. I tried the following but it isn't working. Please help me. Thank you

```js
$('#thedate').datepicker({
  minDate: 0
});

$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {
  var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setSeconds(0);
  if (Date.parse(today) == Date.parse(selectedDate)) {
    alert('This month');
  } else {
    alert('Not this month');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Date: <input type="text" id="thedate">
<button id="checkDate">Check this month or not</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Match the month value using . [`new Date().getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)
2. For day match `new Date().getDate()`

**Updated**
http://jsfiddle.net/9y36pq85/

```
   $('#thedate').datepicker({minDate:0});

$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {
    var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');
    var d= new Date(selectedDate);
    var today = new Date();
    if (d.getMonth() == today.getMonth()) {
        alert('this month');
    } else {
        alert('Not this  month');
    }
    alert(d.getDate() == today.getDate() ?'today':'not today')
});
```

Comment: How can i check today day or not?

Comment: I did..Working fine..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getMonth` and `getYear` methods of the Date object, and compare the 2.

something like

```
$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {
    var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');
    var today = new Date();
    if (today.getYear() === selectedDate.getYear() && today.getMonth() === selectedDate.getMonth()) {
        alert('this month');
    } else {
        alert('Not this  month');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#thedate').datepicker({minDate:0});

$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {
    var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');
    
    var current = moment(selectedDate);
    if (moment().month()== current.month()) {
        alert('this month');
    } else {
        alert('Not this  month');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
Date: <input type="text" id="thedate"/>

<button id="checkDate">Check this month or not</button>
```

You can do like this use month() function of momentjs

```
$('#thedate').datepicker({minDate:0});

$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {
    var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');

    var current = moment(selectedDate);
    if (moment().month()== current.month()) {
        alert('this month');
    } else {
        alert('Not this  month');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/viethien/47odqehb/4/

Comment: Unnecessary library use should be avoided.